# Swing JTable rows don't appear

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jframe

I have been developing a simple database application that have a graphical user interface.  The user interface is designed using Swing, created using Netbeans GUI designer.  The database is accessed via a derby embedded driver.

The problem is: Some rows-the last rows- in the table are hidden till clicked in.

Comment: Did you add the `JTable` to `JScrollPane`? Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Yes I added the jtable to a scrollpane

Comment: A screen shot is available :
https://www.mediafire.com/?vlggdgbxb3r3jdv

Comment: What type of layout manager?

Comment: *"The problem is:"* ..the code.  For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).